# Snow Leopard screen sharing slow to connect

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vnc, screen-sharing

My snow leopard (10.6.7) suddenly refused to connect to another mac (snow leopard 10.6.4) through screen sharing. There is no change except the installation of the latest security update.

If I connect using "MyComputer.local", it tries until timeout with no error message. If I connect using IP address (192.168.0.X), it tries and manage to make the connection only after one minute.

I do not have the same problem connecting with other devices on the same home network, but none of them is snow leopard.

Any help will be appreciated.